# How to run only single http request among several http requests

Tags: jmeter

I had created multiple http requests. But I want to run a http request among the several http request.

Is it possible to run a http request alone ?

Can any one please help?

Comment: Is this a puzzle ? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: For example :- I have 30 http requests in a thread. For that, if I start running all the 30 http requests are running and displaying the result. But I would like to run only the 20th http request. So, is it possible to run only 20th http request?

Comment: check Once Only Controller with If Controller.

Comment: Why not using the `Disable` options? It's so easy to configure. Just right-click on the requests from JMeter-GUI and select "Disable".

Comment: Because in Postman we simply go to the request and resend it.

Answer (score 2):

Just select all requests you don't want to be run in JMeter GUI, and choose `Disable` either in context menu (on right click) or from `Edit` item of JMeter's main menu.

[image: JMeter Disable Request]

---

If you want to enable/disable specific Test Elements from command-line the easiest option would be using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter test. Taurus naturally supports JMeter and it is capable of overriding original JMeter test plan settings via simple [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) configuration file.

References:

- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)
- [Taurus JMeter Executor: Modifications for Existing Scripts](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a particular controller for that that should contain your 30 requests:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller